# How to navigate from a table view to a XIB file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have loaded a XIB file(xyz) which is in the form of tableView
Now I have to load another XIB file(abc) on clicking any cell present in the xyz file . I have written this code in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

```
abc * vc = [[abc alloc] initWithNibName:@"abc" bundle:nil];    
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

It is throwing a SIGABRT error in main. Please help!!

Comment: first check is your vc or self.navigationController is nil

Comment: how to check that ?

Comment: with breakpoint or with NSLog

Comment: NSLog("My Nav VC is %@", self.navigationController);

Comment: The error it is showing is 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle

Comment: I tried printing NSLOG before 1st line and after 1st line but it is not printing anything

Comment: make sure your xib name in abc

Comment: Xcode is caseSensitive with file names. It's not the same "Abc" than "abc".

Comment: @Ashish What was the issue?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR some connection issues with Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in the comment, check whether self.navigationController is nil.
If you're using storyboard, try embedding the ViewController in the NavigationController.You can do so by selecting your view controller in storyboard and then Go to Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller

Further, check whether your xib file's name is indeed "abc"

Answer (score 0):

Select the xib file and open file inspector. Now under Target Membership tick the check mark.

And check either abc view controller or navigationController is nil

```
if (![[abc alloc] initWithNibName:@"abc" bundle:nil]) {
    NSLog(@"xib file with name abc not found");
} else if (!self.navigationController) {
    NSLog(@"Navigation controller is nil");
} else {
    abc * vc = [[abc alloc] initWithNibName:@"abc" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```